# Jquery remove <td> element inside <tr>

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like -

```
<table id="my_table">
<tr>
<td class="">
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="">
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">ABC</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="">
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">XYZ</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="">
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">DSA</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">BDE</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="">
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="">
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">ABC</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="">
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">DSE</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="">
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">WER</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class=" collapse" data-parent="" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">BFD</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class=" collapse" data-parent="" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Parent `<table>` has two `<tr>` elements, and each `<tr>` has 4 `<td>` elements. I want to remove all the `<td>` elements inside `<tr>` except first one. That is output of the HTML should be like -

```
<table id="my_table">
<tr>
<td class="">
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="">
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">ABC</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="">
   <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
      <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="">
               <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
               <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">ABC</td>
               <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                  <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Tried to achieve this with something like -

```
$("#my_table").closest('tr').each (function() {
    $(this).closest('td:not(:first)').remove();
});
```

But, its not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It should be `$("#my_table").find('tr')` or `$("#my_table tr")`. Remember: `.find()` travels down the into the children. `.closest()` travels up the parents. So it should most likely also be `$(this).find('td:not(:first)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to use this way to remove your td elements?

```js
var data = $("#my_table > tbody > tr").each(function() {
  $(this).children('td:not(:first)').remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="">
      <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
        <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="">
              <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
              <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">ABC</td>
              <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
        <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="">
              <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
              <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">XYZ</td>
              <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
        <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="">
              <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
              <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">DSA</td>
              <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
        <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
              <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">BDE</td>
              <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="">
      <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
        <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="">
              <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
              <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">ABC</td>
              <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
        <table class="table1" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="">
              <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
              <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">DSE</td>
              <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                <div class="accordian_ads_data collapse" data-parent="#table1" style="height:0px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
        <table class="" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="">
              <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
              <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">WER</td>
              <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                <div class=" collapse" data-parent="" style="height:0px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="main_row" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;">
        <table class="" style="height:100%; width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 4%;" class="accordian"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></td>
              <td class="td_left" style="width: 35%;text-align: left;">BFD</td>
              <td style="width: 15%">24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" style="padding:0;height:0px;">
                <div class=" collapse" data-parent="" style="height:0px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```